# Certificate passing issue into REST API from AWS IIS

Tags: c#, .net, rest, ssl-certificate

Hi i am facing one issue to pass certificates into Rest API. I have 2 files private key and public key and I have created a .pfx file using those 2 keys and certificate pass is working fine in the visual studio run and local IIS.

But the issue is in the AWS server IIS. Somehow the certificate passed not going through in the server and getting below error from the Rest API.

Error:
An error occurred while sending the request
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I am using below code to generate a certificate and pass into rest api.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Certificate/certificate.pfx"));

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
            };
 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

HttpClient httpClient;

                httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("xxxxxxxx"),
                };
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
                MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("xxxxxxxx", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
                var httpResponseContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

In the server TLS1.2 is enabled and file read permission etc are ok. So not sure why that error is coming from the api response. Can someone help me on this issue please. I am really struggling with this issue but not getting any clue where it is blocked.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253193/discussion-on-question-by-saiful-certificate-passing-issue-into-rest-api-from-aw); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.